# How can I skip compressing one PNG?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compression, png, itunesartwork

*(Note: I have solved this problem, but it took long enough that I'm posting question/answer here.)*

The Xcode build process "optimizes" my PNGs when building. This isn't usually a problem, but iTunesArtwork being processed in this way causes corrupts it so that iTunes not to be able to show it. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read more about Xcode's PNG compression here:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html

While you can turn off PNG optimization/compression entirely using "Compress PNG Files" in your project settings (it's visible only if the project's Base SDK is set to a device SDK, not a simulator SDK), you don't want to do this! Read the link above for details on why, but the gist of it is that the optimization lets the iPhone skip some math that slows down PNG display.

Xcode will only optimize PNG image files that it knows about. To prevent a specific PNG from being optimized, you change its file type so Xcode no longer knows it's a PNG.

1. Select the file in the project window.
2. Choose File->Get Info.
3. On the General tab, change File Type from `image.png` to `file`.

(This is actually the default when you add a file without an extension, which is presumably why iTunesArtwork doesn't have one. But if you're pedantic like me you checked the File Type setting and fixed it.)

Comment: I recommend [disabling Xcode's compression entirely](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html), since it doesn't do good job optimizing and [may make files *slower* to load](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html).

Comment: That's if you're using a third party library that doesn't support Apple's custom compressed PNGs, isn't it? iOS itself is **much** faster with compressed images. Or is that only true of older hardware? It was certainly true last time I tested it.

Comment: Steven Fisher: most of the savings are from 1-byte-per-pixel images, in which there is nothing to byteswap in the first place. I've tested on new hardware, but I don't see why byteswapping would be expensive — it's super simple operation you can do in registers/L1 cache. OTOH reading more data from disk and decompressing more sounds like a real overhead.

Comment: The advantage of *not* byteswapping is that the raw data can be passed straight to the GPU, without going via the CPU first. Yes, it's a simple operation, but it can potentially change the path. I haven't seen any decent tests explaining and showing the performance difference though.

Answer (score 8):

Found another very simple method to disable compression for a single png file. I think this is a better approach than the accepted answer because you don't have to change type (or extension) of file in the local file-system but only in XCode.

Change the file type from `Default - PNG Image` to `Data` in Identity and Type inspector in XCode. See below:

Was:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For all you guys using Xcode 6.4 and above:

Go to: "Targets" - "YourProject Name".

Next go to the "Build Settings" tab. Just below the Tab name click the "Basic" and "Combined" Button.

Next scroll down to the "Packaging" seperator and you will find "Compress PNG Files" set to "Yes" by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Goto your build setting 
2.Search flag Compress PNG files and set it to NO.(default is YES).
```

After this compression of PNG images will be avoided.
Just For more info

Comment: That'll turn off all PNG compression, which is usually not what you want. (But might be sometimes.)