# Artifacts on iOS 8 simulator when using xcassets

Tags: ios, artifacts, xcasset

I'm facing a strange issue, after adding all my images to a xcasset, my app looks malformed (see screenshot) when running it on iOS 8 simulator. Each image is full of artifacts. Before, all my images were simply added to main bundle, and everything worked. I don't have a device with iOS 8 to test on it. Also it works well on versions above iOS 8. If you have any guesses what is the problem, please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to erase content and settings from the simulator? Are your assets vector- or pixel-based?

Comment: @the4kman resetting simulator didn't help. My asset is pixel based.

Comment: I suspect the images themselves are corrupted or somehow in a format not expected by iOS. Maybe try re-exporting the images? Are they JPG or PNG, or something else?

Comment: @picciano Images are PNGs. Tried to re-export, no change.

Comment: Perform a project clean.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal is to support three iOS versions, the current version and the previous two versions.

Try below steps:

1. Remove all caches from User's Library
2. Remove all derived data content of Xcode
3. Clean
4. Clear Trash
5. Quit Xcode
6. Open Xcode
7. Build

It should help you.

Currently 92% devices are running iOS 10 or above

[References (apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)

Comment: Did all the steps, also reinstalled iOS 8 simulator, but it did't help (

Comment: is it coming to only iOS 8

Comment: Yes, another versions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the images do not contain alpha channel - try adding it, otherwise try removing it.

Also check this option (causes similar problems from time to time):
[How can I skip compressing one PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051947/how-can-i-skip-compressing-one-png)